# Android : How to create legends for recyclerview like in piechart

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, legend

In my android application i am using a recyclerview to create a table like structure which will display name,age,place of people as below.
[image]

I don't want to create a header as name,age,place for this recyclerview, instead of that i just want to add a legend/index (I don't know what exactly to call that) like we normally see on piechart,barchart,maps,...so that others can understand what the color indicates.What i want is as below.

Example 1

[image: Example 1]

Example 2

[image: Example 2]

Example 3 :

[image]

I don't know whether its inbuilt in android.I just want to create this with a simple way with effect shape so that i can use it anywhere in my application.How to do it in a simple way ??

Comment: you mean that you want to add labels of your values  like in your "name" label all names are displayed ??? am i right ?

Comment: yes.In a  simple way,like in piechart

Comment: can you show me your item layout file which you use for adapter class?

Comment: I am not using the exact table as shown in the picture.I have lot of recyclerview in my application as grid ,and i want to use lables as header in everywhere.

Comment: yes but a xml file which you used to display name values,age values and place value that one...!

Comment: You can create simple xml layout with this type of design/legend, and put it bottom of the activity / below recyclerview.

Comment: @NaitikSoni Is there any specific view for this in android to make it easy??

Answer (score 0):

**Hi(^_^)** !! put below code into your **recyclerview's item layout file** and using ids of views you can achieve your functionality easily ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_bordeeer"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFC107"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:text="NAME"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5ssp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_bordeeer"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFC107"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:text="JOHN"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10ssp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_bordeeer"
            android:backgroundTint="#4CAF50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="AGE"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5ssp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_bordeeer"
            android:backgroundTint="#4CAF50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="25"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10ssp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_bordeeer"
            android:backgroundTint="#03A9F4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="PLACE"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/place"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5ssp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_bordeeer"
            android:backgroundTint="#03A9F4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="INDIA"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

==> **rounded_bordeeer.xml** file is to achieve **rounded** **border** of your views

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/_4ssp"/>
        <stroke android:width="9px"
            android:color="#d3d3d3" />
    </shape>
```